# How to include the RxAndroidBLE library into my project

Tags: rxandroidble

I have no experience to include an external library to my project. So I need some help.
It says - to include in Android Studio for Gradle

```
compile "com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.10.1"
```

But where should I place this line? And how my project knows where com.polidea located?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your root `build.gradle` file contains

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()     
    }
}
```

2. in your app module in `build.gradle` file add:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.8"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1"
    implementation "com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.10.5"
}
```

3. sync your project